# How to open Mini Controller when a Video is Cast

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast

In my android app I am using `CastCompanionLibrary` to cast videos to a cast device. I want to cast a Video without opening the Extended player i.e. `VideoCastControllerActivity`. Instead, I only want to show the `Mini Controller` when I cast a Video. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

`VideoCastControllerActivity` doesn't open up by itself, it is the client application that needs to call `VideoCastManager.startVideoCastControllerActivity()`. As for MiniController, it is also explained in the docs: in more recent versions of CCL, you can set the xml attribute `auto_setup="true"` in the MiniController xml component in your layout and the rest will be handled by CCL.

Comment: please provide a link instead of saying "it's explained in the docs"  thx

Comment: If you check the CCL project on github, you'll see the docs there.